# Configure query parser to allow only one specific notation to pass an array

Tags: node.js, express

One of my Express `GET` endpoints accepts a few query params and one optional array of strings param. According to the spec, we need to allow the client to pass the array query param using only one notation, the key followed by square brackets: `https://example.com/hello?foo=bar&arr[]=abc&arr[]=xyz`

I want to throw an error if for example `arr` query param is passed like this:

1. `https://example.com/hello?arr=abc&arr=xyz`
2. `https://example.com/hello?arr=abc,xyz`
3. `https://example.com/hello?arr=abc`

I know the last two are interpreted as strings, so I could check if `arr` is not an array and throw an error. But for `arr=abc&arr=xyz`, this is interpreted as an array, but I don't want to allow this way of passing the parameter. Is there a way to configure for example `query parser` to only allow `arr[]` notation for array parameters? Is this even a functionality?

Comment: Write your own middleware that rejects the formats you consider invalid?

Comment: `arr=abc&arr=xyz` and `arr[]=abc&arr[]=xyz` both are arrays when accessing `req.query.arr`. I need to be able to check the format of the query param vs the type, I was hoping this could be done on the express configuration level

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to check `req.query`. You can supply a `"query parser"` setting, or access the raw `req.originalUrl` in middleware. See e.g. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query.